# Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesRelease'

Tags: android, cordova, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to make a deploy of a vue-cli-cordova app for playstore.

My app already works in tests, but when I try npm run npm run cordova-build-android to get an APK,I'm having this issue:

Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesRelease'.

> Crashlytics Developer Tools error.

I've already tried to put the API Key in meta tag like this

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
/>
```

but when I do, I recieve another error:

Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } // Fabrics Maven repository from cordova-plugin-firebase
    }

    dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // google-services dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4' // fabric dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        google() // Google's Maven repository from cordova-plugin-firebase
    }

    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="28.0.3" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```